# elasticsearch total_fields.limit as global

Tags: elasticsearch

I have large docs (more than 1000 fields in each doc) so I need to set 
index.mapping.total_fields.limit = 9000
for each of my indices,

can I set a global config to all indices and change their default limit?
Im using elasticsearch js library, (but I can use API also)

Thanks,
Larry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to use an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) that will apply to all indices as they are created:

```
PUT _template/common-template
{
  "index_patterns": "*",                    <--- applies to all indices
  "order": 10,                              <--- high order to apply the template last
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "mapping": {
        "total_fields": {
          "limit": "9000"                   <--- this setting will apply to all indices
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
     ... common mappings go here...
  }
}
```

Comment: 1.can I do it somewhere in elastic configuration?
so I can tell my Devops that this is one of the prerequisite?
 2. if I will remove the property "mapping", will mapping be automaticlly?

Comment: 1. if you create the template in ES; it will apply automatically without your DevOps needing to do anything; 2. you can remove the mappings section and only leave the settings one

Comment: 1. I mean: I have dockers environment, and we create new environment sometime, so everything start from beginning, I dont want someone to remember doing this configuration.. maybe there is some property for elastic on YML file?

Comment: No there isn't, but if you're doing docker, I can suggest this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560565/how-to-bundle-elasticsearch-templates-with-docker-image/46561199#46561199