# elasticsearch, deploy index templates with docker compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I'm using elastic search and I have created a index template. I'm using docker-compose to deploy elastic search. I would like to have my index template loaded into elastic search at startup.

Is there some `elasticsearch/templates/` folder I could put my index template in, so it get's loaded on startup? For example: `elasticsearch/templates/mytemplate.json`?

Comment: There is not, templates must be loaded using the [REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices.html#index-templates-apis).

Comment: Here is a thread that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46561199/4604579